# Installing last libreoffice by apt-get

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, libreoffice, apt

How to install the last LibreOffice version by the `apt-get` command? I ran the followed commands at a Ubuntu 16.04 and just got version 6.2.8.2 but the last official one is 6.4.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

Comment: hi hildogjr does this help https://superuser.com/a/196867/598224

Comment: Hi @pnorton, I want some way to install without manual download od the `.deb` package and keep the installation up-to-date. Checking at https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice appear that LibreOffice is not anymore official released though PPA to Ubuntu 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second the official developers, LibreOffice-official-version Ubuntu 16.04 should be 5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial10. Because I had manually added `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa` I was able to got libreoffice 6.2.8.2.

To achieve the 6.4 and newer installation they recommend to download the package or simple use `sudo snap install libreoffice`.